# offline google map android

Tags: android, google-maps

I try to follow documents to work with google map API, but it is not work.

My Manifest

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.gogplemap"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />  
        <permission
           android:name="com.example.gogplemap.GOOGLEMAP"
           android:protectionLevel="signature"
           ></permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gogplemap.GoogleMap"/>
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.gogplemap.GoogleMap"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:value="AIzaSyBPQPMrlJk-Ft48z0CWvpWBRcLyrIJJ4X4"/>       
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

My layout activity_google_map.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:id="@+id/map"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

My method setcontentView in GoogleMap.java

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_map);
    }
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you getting any error!!!

Comment: I think this is My error I got on console.                     03-27 02:01:42.384: E/AndroidRuntime(1075): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: try my answer it will work for you!!

Comment: Van Sac Pham if my answer help you out then accept the answer!!

Answer (score 0):

try like this way:it will work for you!!

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidmapview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.androidmapview.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.androidmapview.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidmapview.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="*********************************uw"></meta-data>
    </application>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: I have install the google play services but I can not import the class com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

Comment: @VanSacPham you can do that after you add the google play library to your project!

Answer (score 0):

I can see few errors with what you have done so far:

**1.** First of all if your min SDK is V8 then you have to use `SupportMapFragment` and `FragmentActivity` objects instead of `MapFragment` and `Activity` object. Of course you need to add reference of the `google_support-v4` library to your project as well, so for you map XML file you should write:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**2.** Second, it look like you defined you key the wrong way, instead of:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:value="AIzaSyBPQPMrlJk-Ft48z0CWvpWBRcLyrIJJ4X4"/>
```

you should write:

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBPQPMrlJk-Ft48z0CWvpWBRcLyrIJJ4X4" />
```

**3.** Next, the permissions you are using are incorrect, instead of:

```
 <permission
       android:name="com.example.gogplemap.GOOGLEMAP"
       android:protectionLevel="signature"
       ></permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gogplemap.GoogleMap"/>
```

add this:

```
<permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

don't forget to place your application package instead of the “your.application.package” string in the first two permissions, `"com.example.gogplemap"` in your case.

You can get more information from a blog post I wrote exactly on this topic:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)